# Client side caching of images resized by ImageResizer

Tags: imageresizer

I've done a fair amount of searching, but I really cannot find a straight answer to this:
How do you make client side caching of images resized by ImageResizer to work, i.e. url's on the format `http://<server>/image.jpg?maxwidth=50`?

Using the following setting in web.config seems to make IIS setup output caching for all static files, except the resized images:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Yes, ImageResizer responses are `dynamicContent`, so you would use that node for IIS configuration instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this at the web server (or application) level, but ImageResizer offers a simple way to do it with the [ClientCache plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/clientcache), which is installed by default.

To configure via Web.Config, set the clientcache `minutes` value to the expiry duration you prefer. In the following example we use 24 hours.

`<resizer>
   <clientcache minutes="1440" />
</resizer>`

Comment: I've been trying the ClientCache plugin with the exact same configuration, but I can't see any images being cached. Looking at the response headers there's no cache settings for the images, like "Expires".
I should mention that I use the AzureReader2 plugin, if that could make a difference. Also, I've updated my question with some more information.

Comment: All working now. Since it's a plugin I've been doing `<add name="ClientCache" minutes="1440"/>` in the `plugins` section, instead of directly under the `resizer` section.Follow up question: why is 1440 suggested value? Seems like infinite cache would be what you want. Any way of doing that, or is using a very large number of minutes the only thing you can do?

Comment: You can use a very large number, but not infinity. Also, the XML in your comment is incorrect and does absolutely nothing, so if you noticed a change in behavior it was unrelated.